# Chern class of line bundle of principal divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Quick question that I could not find elsewhere (beeing new to the subject): Let $X$ be some complex manifold, $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$ and $\mathcal{K}_X$ the sheaf of meromorphic functions on $X$. Then there is natural a map $\mathcal{L}:\text{Div}(X) \to \text{Pic}(X)$ mapping a divisor to a line bundle (cf. Huybrechts, Cor.2.3.10). In fact, this map is up to iso simply the map $\delta : H^0(X,\mathcal{K}^\ast _X / \mathcal{O}^\ast _X) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^\ast _X)$ from the long exact cohom. sequence from the ses $0 \to \mathcal{O}^\ast _X \to \mathcal{K}^\ast _X \to \mathcal{K}^\ast _X / \mathcal{O}^\ast _X \to 0$. Moreover, the first chern class $c_1 : H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^\ast _X) \simeq \text{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the morphism in the long exact cohom seq. from $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}^\ast _X \to 0$. Now we know: A principal divisor $(f)=\sum \text{ord}_Y(f)[Y]$ is image of a $f \in H^0(X,\mathcal{K}^\ast _X) = \mathcal{K}^\ast _X(X)$ and therefore, I think:
$\text{im } \phi:H^0(X,\mathcal{K}^\ast _X) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{K}^\ast _X / \mathcal{O}^\ast _X) = \ker \mathcal{L}$, so any principal divisor should be mapped to the trivial bundle in $\text{Pic}(X)$.

Question: Then the chern class of it should be $c_1(\mathcal{L}(f))=0$, and also any two line bundles that come from are linearly equivalent divisors have the same chern class. Is this correct? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, the line bundle associated to a principle divisor is always trivial, hence has trivial first Chern (this is capitalized btw, after Shiing-Shen Chern) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the first chern class of a principal divisor is $0$: in fact this statement lies in the definition of "divisor".

You can think as Chern classes as ***cycles*** (that is, the generalization of divisors to higher codimension) rather than cohomology classes. So you can think that Chern classes associate to a vector bundle $E$ on $X$ a cycle $c_i(X)$.

Considering the space of cycles is not relevant enough: you quotient your space of cycles by *rational equivalence* (that is, two cycles are equivalent if they differ from a "principal" cycle). You obtain a nice space called **Chow group** $CH^*(X)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_group.

In the particular case of line bundles, the first Chern class associate to a line bundle $L$ the (equivalent class of) the divisor given by the zeros of some generic global section. Starting from a divisor $D$, you can define a line bundle $L(D)$: in fact you just go the opposite direction. In terms of cycle, you have $c_1(L(D))\equiv D$.

Finally, you can go from the Chow group to the cohomology of your variety $H^{2*}(X,\mathbb{Q})$ using Poincaré duality (equivalent cycles have same image in cohomology!), that's why we often say $c_1(L)\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. Principal divisor are already $0$ in the Chow group, thus so are their images in cohomology.